# How to specify a tag and branch on jenkins

Tags: jenkins, bitbucket

I need to retrieve project from bitbucket, which is relevant to specific tag and only specific branch in bitbucket by running the jenkins job I have setup. 
I have several branches in bitbucket. please see the below configuration.

[first pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b1CS2.png)
[/second pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2qwOI.png)

I have pass tag name as parameter to the jenkins job and that can give me project, relevant to that tag. But if I need code only from master branch. how do I lock down other branches or specify master branch here. At this movement it is giving code from any branch relevant to the tag.

Comment: A tag should just point to a specific commit on a branch, and generally should just be static once created. Is that tag changing? If it is the tag is always going to point to the whatever it was most recently pointed at, on the branch that commit is on.  Really you should just make that entire field take the parameter value, and just specify the entire string on the parameter line when you start the build.

Comment: Thank you very much for reply...! ,yes tag name is changing. Actually tag is representing our software release version. Problem is , if we give the tag name ,which is not relevant to the master(production branch) let say test branch tag called "tag_test_v1" , as a parameter to  this job(accidentally), It will give that point and build the wrong software release. I need to stop that. I need to run this job only for Production tag let say "Tag_Prod_v1".
normally we are developing on the test branch and time to time merge that branch on to the production( master) branch . please see second pic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use the [Git Parameter Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Git+Parameter+Plugin) to do this. Give the parameter whatever name you like.

From the Parameter Type drop down you want to select `Tag` (Or if you also want the tips of your branches available select the `Branch or Tag` option).  Then in the tag filter field you're going to set something like `Tag_Prod_*` This should grab all of the production tags in the repo.  If you selected the branch or tags option you can also set the branch filter to just be master, but this won't affect the tags listed.

When you go to perform the build you should see a list box that gets populated based on the parameter configuration, you can then scroll through the box to find which one you want to build.

Comment: yes, this is helpful. but there is no option to list down tags , only belongs to the master branch. it is giving all tags. anyway there's a tag filter, I have use pattern git tag -l PROD* . it's working...! thanks